# How to convert a raw video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a raw video that has the following properties:

- 25 FPS
- UYVY Codec
- 876 MBit/s
- AVI Container

I want to convert this raw file to another container using `ffmpeg`. Right now the problem is that the output video is being compressed. Any idea how to do this without compressing the output file. I have tried:

`ffmpeg -i video.avi -r out.avi`

and it did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that **ffmpeg is depricated** in Ubuntu and other distros:

[image]

`avconv` is the one you want to use which is in in the `libav-tools` package and can be installed with the following line:

`sudo apt-get install libav-tools`

So here are some ways you can do it:

**FFMPEG** (Deprecated in 12.04+)

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.avi`
`ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.mp4`
`ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.mkv`
`ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.mpg`

**AVCONV**

`avconv -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.avi`
`avconv -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.mp4`
`avconv -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.mkv`
`avconv -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.mpg`

Am assuming that when you say "convert to anything else" and then you add that the output should not be compressed (And then I just so happen to see the bitrate) am thinking the original file, the input is RAW inside an avi container. If this is the case, the above options will work. They will just copy the content to another container, maintaining the 25fps, bitrate and overall quality.

If you do not want to copy the content, simply remove the part that says "-vcodec copy -acodec copy" and avconv/ffmpeg will take care of it.

**NOTE** - As mentioned by LordNeckBeard, the MP4 example will not work on Raw.

Comment: Just to clarify: Ubuntu switched to libav, and "deprecated" the libav version of the ffmpeg binary, but do not assume that the real ffmpeg from FFmpeg is not longer being developed. [Quite the opposite!](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=summary)

Comment: Also, rawvideo is not supported by the MP4 container (at least via ffmpeg).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thanks for the information about the MP4. Also in the answer I mention in bold that it was deprecated in Ubuntu. Same as OpenOffice was and others. They still continue but are not found by default on the system. The downvote was also not needed ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Use ConvertMe!

[image]
A fine media converter you have never used before...
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/ConvertMe!?content=153277

Comment: The OP wants to use ffmpeg.

Comment: Well, that one is a "frontend based on ffmpeg". :)

Answer (score 1):

run:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -sameq -r 25 out.avi
```

---

is your video really encoded with 800 MBit/s?

you can specifically set the video bit rate

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -b:v 876104k -maxrate 1200000 -bufsize 876104k out.avi
```

Comment: try setting the bit rate manually, and/or force frame rate to 25

Comment: that didn't work neither ??
Either both buffer size and max rate or neither must be specified
[mpeg4 @ 00000000020ec880] bitrate tolerance too small for bitrate

Comment: let's run it without the frame rate flag then. What happens.

Comment: [Do not use `-sameq`](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524): it does not mean "same quality" and has been removed upstream.